# Correct renormalization of the product of two probabilistic models

Tags: probability, distributions, normalization

I came across these two papers combining an energy-based model (EBM) with a probabilistic generative model: [[Xiao et al., 2020]](https://invertibleworkshop.github.io/INNF_2020/accepted_papers/pdfs/4.pdf) and [[Xiao et al., 2021]](https://openreview.net/forum?id=5m3SEczOV8L).

In [[Xiao et al., 2020]](https://invertibleworkshop.github.io/INNF_2020/accepted_papers/pdfs/4.pdf), the new model is defined as:

\begin{equation}
p_{\phi, \theta}(x) = \frac{p_{\phi}(x)e^{-E_{\theta}(x)}}{\int p_{\phi}(x)e^{-E_{\theta}(x)} dx} = \frac{p_{\phi}(x) e^{-E_{\theta}(x)}}{Z_{\phi, \theta}}
\end{equation}

where $p_{\phi}(x)$ is a probabilistic generative model and $p_{\theta}(x) = \frac{e^{-E_{\theta}(x)}}{\int e^{-E_{\theta}(x)} dx}$ is an EBM.

In [[Xiao et al., 2021]](https://openreview.net/forum?id=5m3SEczOV8L), the authors use a VAE generator $p_{\phi}(x, z) = p_{\phi}(z)p_{\phi}(x|z)$ and define the new model as:

\begin{equation}
    h_{\phi, \theta}(x,z) = \frac{p_{\phi}(x, z) e^{-E_{\theta}(x)}}{\int p_{\phi}(x)e^{-E_{\theta}(x)}dx} = \frac{p_{\phi}(x, z) e^{-E_{\theta}(x)}}{Z_{\phi, \theta}}
\end{equation}

My question is: **shouldn't the renormalization in the second case be $Z_{\phi, \theta} = \int p_{\phi}(x, z)e^{-E_{\theta}(x)}dx$?**

Comment: No, your $Z_{\phi,\theta}$ would depend on $z$ thus it's not a norming constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't look at the references but the paper's formula is correct. Indeed (in your notation), the normalization constant of $h_{\phi,\theta}(x,z)$ is

\begin{align*}
Z_{\phi,\theta} &= \iint p_{\phi}(x,z)e^{-E_\theta(x)}\,dz dx\\ 
& = \int\left(\int p_{\phi}(x,z) dz\right) e^{-E_\theta(x)}\,dx\\ 
&= \int p_\phi(x) e^{-E_\theta(x)}\,dx,
\end{align*}

where $p_\phi(x) = \int p_{\phi}(x,z) dz$ is the marginal distribution of $X$ obtained from the joint $p_{\phi}(x,z)$.

So $\int p_{\phi}(x,z)e^{-E_\theta(x)}\,dx$ can't be the norming constant of the joint since it depends on $z$.